# config.static_cache_control ignored no Cache-Control header

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I use ruby 2.1.6p336 rail 3.2.11
I'd like to see Cache-Control header for /assets
I set next values in config/environnment/production.rb

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
config.static_cache_control = "public, max-age=31536000"
# and try with this too:
config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://mydomain"
```

There is no Cache-Control (but ETag exists)

I recompile assets as writed here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/rubyonrails-talk/HQsICnjkAlI/hs5WgJ3whkgJ

My Assets is compiled good, with hash tag and with packed gz variants.

How to diag or debug what is the problem?
Which source code work with static_cache_control and Cache-Control?

PS
Some times debug or view sources is helpful.
But when i try to see gems folder, rails-3.2.11 directory is empty.
System library folder /usr/local/libs/... have no rails too.
Strange but all work fine, where rails core files?

Comment: Are you sure it's rails serving the assets (as opposed to nginx / apache)?

Comment: Yes nginx serve static files excellent. Cache-Control is available for setup simple too. I have want to setup it later. The rails config is some better for reasons: all setup is in one place, and do not need to su for edit nginx.conf. And main thing is that it must work. It is in documentation: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#cdns-and-the-cache-control-header

Comment: The rails settings don't apply when it's nginx serving the files directly.

Comment: Yes of course, I have no setup nginx static folders yet, (will later). Currently all trafic redirected to unicorn socket.

Comment: I have done nginx setup now, with expires gzip and so on... It work fine as supposed. Cache-Control appears in header and data is compressed. But I can not understand why this functional is not worked in rails as described in documentation? Some times it is necessary to use.